# Splitting a large file by column with values in the header as file names

Tags: text-processing, awk, text

I have a large tab-delimited text file which contains a header and data. I want to split the file into smaller files by column, with the header excluded, and the files named as the column name.

```
pos    red    green    blue
123    0|0    1|0      0|0
321    1|0    1|0      0|0
231    0|0    0|0      0|0
213    0|0    1|0      1|0
```

and I need to split the files into:

```
pos.txt:
123
321
231
213

red.txt:
0|0
1|0
0|0
0|0

green.txt:
1|0
1|0
0|0
1|0

blue.txt:
0|0
0|0
0|0
1|0
```

I tried:

```
awk 'NR==1{h=$0; next}
!seen[$3]++{f=${h[$3]}".txt"; print >> f}' infile
```

but it hasn't been working...

Comment: Do you know for certain that the entire file is four columns of data?

Comment: Can there ever be space(s) in a field value (or a header value)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i; next}
{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {print $i > a[i]".txt"}}' infile
```

On header line this saves the value of each field in an array then for the rest of the lines it prints each field to the corresponding filename.